# Save picture from one database to another

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a save button for user to save into their database, but I having a difficulty on getting the name of the image i select.

[Save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZ5x.png)

I know using `  $image=$_GET["image"]; will get the name if the image but I dont know how to get the name outside the php because I'm using popup module.

```
  <div id="modal01" class="w3-modal " style="padding-top:0" 
 onclick="this.style.display='none'">
<span class="w3-button w3-black w3-xlarge w3-display-topright">×</span>
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
  <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
  <p id="caption"></p>
<form action="save.php" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is my code on retrieving picture from database:

```
<?php

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<div class='grid-item'><img src='images/{$row['image']}' onclick=onClick(this) style='width:98%' /></div>
                                                                            ";}                     
            mysqli_close($db);
                        ?>
```

Comment: you have `method="post"` but you swear `$_GET['image']` will work?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i'm sorry i forget to change it

Comment: I don't write JS much but what is `onclick=onClick` suppose to do?

Comment: @user3783243 is for when click the picture, it pop up a module of the picture

Comment: You can either parse the picture name+extension into query string or save it in a session and then run an insert query on database where you want to save it using $_GET or $_POST method.